# Get access to inner object to check if they are the same

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am working on a unit test where I want to assert that the object coming back is the same as the model.

```
        var actual = scope.InstanceUnderTest.GetContent(expectedId);
        var newFileStreamer = new FileStreamer(scope.TestDocument.Data, "application/octet-stream");
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.Result.Equals(newFileStreamer));
```

actual.Result appears to be one level away from the object that is the same as newFileStreamer:

[image]

How do I get access to the inner filestream object to check if they are the same?

Comment: Do you simply need to cast one of the objects ?

Comment: I tried this with the same result: Assert.IsTrue((FileStreamer)actual.Result == newFileStreamer);

Comment: It should error on that line and say something like "No way to compare `some object type` to `some other object type`. What does the exception say?

Comment: Exception is: Assert.IsTrue failed.

Comment: Then do the operation again but do something like `if(actual.Result == newFileStreamer)` so you can see the actual internal exception of the comparison.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. actual.Result object is a Task<IHTTPActionResult> and newFileStreamer is FileStreamer. But as you can see the actual FileSTreamer object is embedded in actual.Result on the watch window.

Comment: Then can you compare like this:`if((FileStreamer)actual.Result == newFileStreamer)`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at your screen shot and you can see that the Object types are not the same one is of type `System.Web.Http.IHttpAction the other is of type WebService. what are you trying to Compare actually as being Equal.. `use == when comparing value` use .Equals when doing Object Equality`

Comment: @MethodMan Yes I see that. So how do I get access to the FileStreamer object that is within IHTTPAcitionResult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not one level away, the debugger shows it that way because it performs a cast to the correct type. If you right-click on the second-node and select add-watch you will see that the expression watched contains a cast.

To check for the internals you could use reflection.
Note that is **not recomended** to test for private field in unit testing, but if you really want to, here is some code:

```
var actual = scope.InstanceUnderTest.GetContent(expectedId);

var type = actual.Result.GetType();
var dataField = type.GetField("_data",
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
var contentTypeField = type.GetField("_contentType",
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance);

Assert.IsTrue(dataField.GetValue(actual.Result) == scope.TestDocument.Data);
Assert.IsTrue(contentTypeField.GetValue(actual.Result) == "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I compare them?

Comment: The return value `Equals` and `==` depends on the implementation of `FileStreamer`, probably it is checking whether or not they are the same instance. You would need to check the values of `_contentType` and `_data`.

Comment: how can I check them if they are private in the class?

Comment: using reflection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I changed this to the answer as it directly answers original question.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for .Equals() for reference types is to check for reference equality (i.e. do they point to the same object on the heap). Since one of the two objects you instantiate just before your assert then there is no way they would ever be considered the same object (since there is no way for another object to get a reference to newFileStreamer between its instantiation and the assert).

If you have not yet [provided an overload for .Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) for your fileStreamer type then you can solve your problem by doing so and stating within the method what exactly would constitute being equal.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. How would I check the inner private fields then for comparison?

Comment: If you are unit testing you should not be concerned with private fields. With a unit test you should call some public method/property and then check that you get the expected outcome. If there is no way to determine whether your code worked correctly in a test then there is no way it could go wrong in a real implementation either (since no code interacting with it would be able to detect the effects either)

Comment: If your question was concerning overriding `Equals`: when you override `Equals` in a class's method, it gives you access to the other class's private fields (as long as you are comparing 2 objects of the same class).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments it seems like this should be fine:

```
if( (FileStreamer)actual.Result == newFileStreamer) {
    //do work here
}
```

Or I guess

```
if( (actual.Result as FileStreamer) == newFileStreamer) {
    //do work here
}
```